Nonlinear optics begins with a presentation on the polarization expansion, for both insulators and metals. how to reconcile this for metals?
Typically a first presentation of nonlinear optics discusses a taylor expanded form of polarizability. That makes sense (to me) in insulators, where there are bound electrons that are polarized. But, this description is typically extended to metals too, yet conduction electrons are free. How do we reconcile describing nonlinear optical effects using higher order terms in the polarization expansion with the fact that electrons are free (not polarized, or not 'polarizable')?

Electrons in metals are delocalized but it doesn't mean they are free.

After all, they are bound to the metal. They cannot leave it. So they feel some potential holding them up.
